# What is the version and library support on cloudant server?

Tags: javascript, cloudant

Cloudant use javascript for design document on server. Which is map+reduce and update handler. But I have not seen it mention what version it could be used on current server

Is it support ES6? What library we could called on that? Can we call Math and Date?

Can we do http call? Is it compatible with node js?

I want to call http in updatehandler, suppose I use facebook auth and have user send access token to my db so I could get userID from it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have sent this to support@cloudant.com (actually I sent question to cloudant before posted here, but just got answer)

> Cloudant uses the SpiderMonkey 1.8.5 engine for Javascript 
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/1.8.5
>
> It implements ES-5 (ECMA 262 5th Edition), not ES 6.
>
> The Cloudant view server cannot make outbound HTTP requests (or indeed
>   do any kind of file or socket activity).

Answer (score 0):

This is something only cloudant are going to be able to give a definitive answer on, you should email support@cloudant.com or open a ticket through the dashboard.